# How to load debug symbols in LLDB?

Tags: c, clang, llvm, lldb

I'm trying to debug a curses application with command line LLDB but the experience is a complete nightmare: once the first breakpoint is hit LLDB output mixes with the rendered application interface making everything unusable. To work around this issue I tried to load the application in another terminal and then attach to process from LLDB but when I do that it doesn't load symbols therefore LLDB prints assembly code instead of C making identification of variables and instructions impossible.

How can I load the symbols in LLDB before attaching to an external process?

Comment: Attaching and launching aren't particularly different to lldb, it should be able to find symbols either way.  One common problem is that when you launched the process outside of lldb, the shell launched an installed version of the binary or the library you were debugging, and not your debug build?  You can use the command `image list <BinaryWithoutSymbols>` to make sure you launched/loaded the binary you thought you did.